# Is it possible to install an iOS app in the simulator through Xcode without launching it immediately?

Tags: xcode, ios, ios-simulator

I want to verify that the default values in Settings.app are correct before the app updates them when it is launched.

Comment: I'm curious why you can't check Settings.app before your build and launch the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just install, but you can..

.. just check the settings programmatically in your -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method during the initial startup. If you want to see them before any of your app code runs, you can always just change your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so that it doesn't actually create and setup your root view controller. Then kill the app and check the Settings.app to see if things look proper to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is. As http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW2 states "When you run your application, Xcode installs it in iOS Simulator or on a device, and launches it."

Answer (score 0):

After clicking 'Build and Run', I click 'Quit' in the Console before the app launches.